# como llamar la ultima busqueda en SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un proyecto para la universidad que necesita buscar multiple clientes, y una vez encontrado la ID del cliente poder ver y modificar los cambios de dicho cliente.

la parte de la busqueda ya la solucione pero no se como hacer para guardar la informacion de la ultima busqueda para poder modificar dicho usuario en otra pantalla.

agradeceria si alguien pudiera colaborarme con las funciones o el codigo que algo asi requiere.

estoy trabajando en PHP con base de datos Mysql PHPmyadmin y Xampp.

Comment: Debes mostrar el código para que podamos ayudarte. Revisa cómo formular una pregunta.

Comment: la situacion es que no tengo un codigo que mostrar, por eso pregunto

Comment: Dices que ya tienes la búsqueda pon eso ya que hay muchas maneras de hacer una cadena de conexión dependiendo que versión uses, ademas explica mejor " ver y modificar los cambios de dicho cliente" realmente no entiendo que quieres hacer.

Comment: me piden crear una pagina de busqueda que me permita imprimir los datos en una tabla, luego en otra pagina tomar esos datos de la busqueda anterior y modificar el registro de dicha ID en la base de datos, pero no se como guardar la informacion de la busqueda para poder modificarla despues

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende muy bien, y parecería que estás pidiendo todo un sistema completo. Por favor, si quieres que te ayudemos debes decir lo que estás intentando y qué errores / dificultades tienes sobre ese código. Es imposible que alguien se ponga a explicarte desde cero cómo montar una base de datos o un sistema de búsqueda / actualización. La finalidad de este sitio es ayudar sobre problemas concretos.

Comment: Busca en Google: CRUD con PHP y la extensión PDO. Aprenderás a realizar todas las funciones sobre los registros (Crear, Leer, Actualizar y Borrar).

Comment: gracias ya pude hacer algo similar a lo que tenia intencion de hacer... si me sale alguna duda volvere a aparecer